# Botpress and Teams integration: HTTP status code BadRequest

Tags: microsoft-teams, chatbot, botpress

I'm having an issue on integrating Botpress with Microsoft Teams.

I followed their docs https://botpress.com/docs/cloud/channels/teams/ and this video https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=botpress+teams.

I made everything that is asked. Microsoft account, Azure account, Teams account, Register an app on azure portal, go to Bot Framework to configure the bot and connect to the channel. But there is no bot's answer... the issue is "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code BadRequest". I verified the webhook and there are no typos.

Anyone here knows what it could be?

Renan

Comment: Please have look into this document-https://www.askhandle.com/blog/botpress-and-teams-integration-http-status-code-badrequest